# Azure Devops Merge only specific commit

Tags: azure-devops

Azure Devops
Scenario : I have branch dev and master. There is commit in dev branch AS Commit1, Commit2, Commit 3 and Commit4 and all this changes release on dev site. Now I have approval for Commit1 and Commit3 to release on production. So how can I merge only commit1 and commit3 from dev branch to master branch

Comment: Btw, you tagged this azure-devops but not git. Are you looking for a UI specific solution without using Git command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Important Note:** I'm sure you know this but I think it's worth mentioning that you haven't actually tested *exactly* what you intend to release. You may benefit from having another branch, say `release`, where you put the stuff you decide to release, and then you can periodically reset `dev` to `master` to clean it up. (And if you do this I would consider calling `dev` something like `next` like [gitworkflows](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows), which is a similar concept.)

**Solution 1** (Most General):

Create a new branch from `master`, cherry-pick the commits you want from `dev`, and merge this "release" branch into `master`.

**Solution 2** (Works if your `dev` branch has merge commits for each commit brought into `dev`, and those commits' parent is `master`.):

Create a new branch from `master`, merge in each of the branches for the commits, and merge this "release" branch into `master`.

**Solution 3** (Works if your `dev` history is linear after `master`, and if you never intend to bring in commit 2):

Disclaimer: this is more of an academic answer and I likely wouldn't actually use this solution in your scenario...

Create a new branch from `master`, and then perform 3 merges:

```
git switch -c release master
git merge Commit1 # take commit1
git merge -s ours Commit2 # merge commit2 but ignore it's changes!
git merge Commit3 # take commit3

# merge release branch into master
git switch master
git merge release
```